# EF 4.4 InverseProperty does not quite inverse

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

This might really be something obvious but I'm not sure why my InverseProperty annotation does not work the other way.

I have this 2 classes (simplified):

```
public class Cluster
{
    [Key]
    public int ClusterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80, ErrorMessage = "DimensionCluster Name cannot be more than 80 characters in length.")]
    [Display(Name = "DimensionCluster Name")]
    public string ClusterName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("DimensionCluster")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Dimension> Dimensions { get; set; }

}

public class Dimension
{
    [Key]
    public int DimensionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Dimension Name cannot be more than 80 characters in length.")]
    [Display(Name = "Dimension Name")]
    public string DimensionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Definition")]
    public string ShortDefinition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DimensionCluster Name")]
    public int ClusterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClusterId")]
    public virtual Cluster DimensionCluster { get; set; }


}
```

The InverseProperty annotation above does not work. I get:

> The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Dimensions' on type
>   'PDguide.Models.Cluster' is not valid. The property 'DimensionCluster'
>   is not a valid navigation property on the related type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PDguide.Models.Dimension]'.
>   Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection
>   navigation property.

Tried a lot of MSDN documents and SO answers. And I finally tried it the other way (code below), and it worked!

```
public class Cluster
{
    [Key]
    public int ClusterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80, ErrorMessage = "DimensionCluster Name cannot be more than 80 characters in length.")]
    [Display(Name = "DimensionCluster Name")]
    public string ClusterName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Dimension> Dimensions { get; set; }

}

public class Dimension
{
    [Key]
    public int DimensionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Dimension Name cannot be more than 80 characters in length.")]
    [Display(Name = "Dimension Name")]
    public string DimensionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Definition")]
    public string ShortDefinition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DimensionCluster Name")]
    public int ClusterId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClusterId")]
    [InverseProperty("Dimensions")]
    public virtual Cluster DimensionCluster { get; set; }

}
```

I have read somewhere (I could not find that reference now, or I may have inferred it incorrectly) that you can specify the InverserProperty annotation on either end of the relationship. But that does not seem to be the case here?

Am I right in my understanding that InverseProperty should work with either property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. In *Programming Entity Framework: Code First*
by Lerman and Miller it says on page 72

> You can place the annotations on either end of the relationship (or both ends if you
>   want).

When I look in the current EF source, it seems that only collection properties of type `ICollection<T>` are recognized as valid inverse properties. So I think that changing the type of your `Dimensions` property into `ICollection<Dimension>` would allow you to put the `InversePropertyAttribute` there as well.

Comment: Just to add to the answer: `IEnumerable<T>` generally cannot be used as a navigation property. No attribute will work on it nor any mapping with Fluent API.

Comment: @Slauma. Good to know. I now notice I never even tried, if only because it's impossible to `Add` or `Remove` with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold and Slauma. Yes, changing my property to an ICollection worked.